# How can I load a nib/xib file within a web view in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

How can I load a nib/xib file within a web view in Cocoa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A xib is an xml form that gets compiled into a nib.  A nib is a way for the designer to automate the creation of native iOS UIViews.

The UIWebView is a UIView that loads web content (not native iOS UIViews).  Think of it as a window into some web page content.  A nib/xib is just a way to layout the native view that houses the UIWebView that is a window into web content.  the UIWebView loads web content and not native UIViews.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> You use the UIWebView class to embed web content in your application.
>   To do so, you simply create a UIWebView object, attach it to a window,
>   and send it a request to load web content. You can also use this class
>   to move back and forward in the history of webpages, and you can even
>   set some web content properties programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you really intend to load a nib/xib based environment within a web page (whatever if it is within a cocoa web view or not) then there is the [cappuccino framework](http://cappuccino.org/) which is intended to do this. Note that this will actually be html code behind.